# How to link a JS file externally?

Tags: javascript

I faced this problem.The Condition needed is that the external file should not include script tag.But in order to call a function the script tag is needed.The code is a mere example.Also is there any other alternative to link the External JS file.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="Friendship.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for the external JS is:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>

function mySpace()
{
document.getElementById("playa").innerHTML="Friendship is always a sweet responsibility, never an opportunity.
";
}
</script>
<body>
<h1><tt>Friendship</tt></h1>
<p id="playa">"One of the most beautiful qualities of true friendship is to understand and to be understood.
"</p>
<button type="button" onclick="mySpace()">Click Here !</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it is compulsory that if one wants to link an external JS file he must make sure that,the file that is to be linked should not contain an HTML code,right ?

Comment: But while linking the file you will need an HTML code too,also you will need a <script> tag.If we consider your condition you mean to say that there is no need to call an HTML code;is it possible to write the JS code without an HTML declaration ? If yes! will it execute properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Javascript file, should only contain JavaScript code. It should not contain HTML, CSS or any other markup.

Based on your example above, you should have the following two files:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Link to external JavaScript file -->
    <script src="friendship.js"></script>
    <h1><tt>Friendship</tt></h1>
    <p id="playa">"One of the most beautiful qualities of true friendship is to understand and to be understood."</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="mySpace()">Click Here !</button>
</body>
</html>
```

### friendship.js

```
// This is a comment
function mySpace()
{
    document.getElementById("playa").innerHTML="Friendship is always a sweet responsibility, never an opportunity.";
}
```

#### Notes

The `friendship.js` is pure JavaScript (or comments as per my example above). You should not add any HTML tags to the JavaScript file such as `<html>`, `<body>`, etc. You also do not need to include `<script>` tags which will generate errors.

> is it possible to write the JS code without an HTML declaration

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this, but I'll attempt to explain. If you were to visit `http://www.example.com/friendship.js` then you would be shown the raw JavaScript code in that file. The code would not be executed automatically. You will need to initiate the JavaScript from an HTML file itself, just as you've done in your HTML with `onclick="mySpace()"`.

Comment: Your code is precise.Sorry for the late reply.When I asked you the question I meant,in the external JS file is it mandatory that there should be no HTML markup and if there is none,will the program run on an event ? That's what I was asking you.